# Can you give me an example of a one-to-one function of two variables?

Tags: function, one-to-one

I need a one-to-one function f(x,y) with two variables, whose range is one-dimensional.

Comment: See This Link I Think It's Work https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25879/onto-and-one-to-one-of-a-2-variable-function

Comment: The function in the link is not one-to-one actually